# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).slider is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, errors, jquery-ui

i am trying to use the jQuery-ui function: slider():
here's my code that i wrote inside the jQuery(document).ready...:

```
jQuery("#slider-wp").slider()
```

and in my functions.php file i wrote this code to call the jQuery library specific to slider():

```
function jquery_scripts(){
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-slider'); 
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery_scripts');
```

when i loaded my page i recevied this error:

[image]

i tried to look into many ressources on the internet but without success.

here's the shortcode in my functions.php file where i want to add the slider:

```
function rangeSlider(){
ob_start();
include 'rangeSliderfct.php';
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('tarifs_slider', 'rangeSlider');
```

and here's the included php file:

```
<input type="text" name="value">
<div id="slider-wp"></div>
```

thanks for the ideas...

Comment: You want the slider on an admin page?

Comment: how are you loading the file which calls `jQuery("#slider-wp").slider()`? does it have jQuery and the slider as dependencies? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: @vancoder i am using on Front page on the site

Comment: @admcfajn it is a php file that is called within a Shortcode, i will add the shortcode and the HTML code to the question

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear; the function is not exist. It would help if you looked at your dependencies. You need jQuery Core, the jQuery UI library, and the jQuery Slider library. But no worries, you should use the dependency handling from WP API via [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and his internal handles to load in the correct order.

```php
wp_register_script(
    'your-jquery-slider',
    plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . './js/your-jquery-slider.js',
    [
        'jquery-ui-core',
        'jquery-ui-slider',
    ]
);
wp_enqueue_script( 'your-jquery-slider' );
```

With these parameters, you make sure that the libraries are in place and right order. The handle `jquery` is not necessary, because the WP API define jQuery as dependency for `jquery-ui-core`, see [this documentation table](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#more-information). The jQuery UI Effects are not included with the `jquery-ui-core` handle, so you need the handle for the slider `jquery-ui-slider`.

Note. Use the register function and then enqueue to give other plugins the chance to remove them, is clean, and have more control for everyone.

Comment: thank you, but i found the solution, i called the jquery-ui library directly from the url and it worked: 
`function load_plugin_scripts() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-slider','https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js', array('jquery'), false, false);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_plugin_scripts' );`

Comment: Actually, you fixed it by switching from `admin_enqueue_scripts` - which won't work on the site's home page - to `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: You should not enqueue the jQuery UI Library from external, because it is inside the WP Core and you risk, that you have no control about loading, multiple load of the same library.

Comment: @bueltge thank you for your insight, i will keep that in mind